# NT Kernal system process stopping my application from working on port 443

Tags: windows-server-2016

We are having an issue with a windows system/process blocking port 443 for us.
We are trying to get another application to use port 443, but the NT Kernal is using port 443 according to some of the checks we did.
Netstat -ano to get the PID (which is 4).

In task manager we established it’s the NT Kernal, but we cant disable it or edit it for obvious reasons...

•   We are using windows server 2016 with a windows 10 OS.
•   It is a physical machine

We have disabled IIS and pretty much every other application. NO skype or team viewer installed either.

Please advise us on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you disable IIS?

Comment: I uninstalled in in server manager